# Trouble with for loops in Python 3: getting the index in string2 of an element from string1

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, indices, vigenere

I am trying to write a program that will take a file and encode it using the Viginère cipher.  I've run into a little bump with indices.  I've defined my strings `text` and `alphabet` like this:

```
import string

alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase
ciphertext = open("black_hole.txt","r")
ciphertext = ciphertext.read()
text = ""

for i in range(len(ciphertext)):
    if ciphertext[i].isalpha() == True:
        text = text + ciphertext[i]
```

My trouble starts when I try to write this for loop:

```
for i in range(len(text)):
    print(alphabet.index(text[i]))
```

I get the ValueError "substring not found".  I find this strange since text[i] is always a letter as well as a string.

Please let me know if I haven't posed this question clearly enough!

Comment: What about upper case letters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in range(len(text)):
    print(alphabet.index(text.lower()[i]))
```

just add lower() and it will work

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Kevin in comments, you are probably missing uppercase.

You can use `alphabet[ord(text[i].lower()) - ord('a')]` instead of `index`.